# form to conditionally display fields based on array position

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

the following rails controller action, creates an array of records to be created:

```
  @guests = []
  @quantity.times do
    @guests << Guest.new
  end
```

Then the form invokes the array of records to be created in the following manner

```
<%= form_tag guests_path do %>
  <% @guests.each do |guest| %>
    <%= fields_for 'guests[]', guest do |f| %>
```

The goal is to render some fields only for the first of these records/

How can the index value of the first guest be invoked (various attempts such as `if @guests[0]` generate errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [each with index](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/each_with_index)

```
<%= form_tag guests_path do %>
 <% @guests.each_with_index do |guest,index| %>
  # Do something with index
  <%= fields_for 'guests[]', guest do |f| %>
```